# How to place only 4 boxes on screen within scroll element?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have an element with certain width (height can change) and scrollbar. There are a boxes in it. Box sizes is equal to half of width/height of element with scrollbar. I want to show only 4 initial boxes in scroll element, before it scrolled. But, if I uncomment fifth box everything breaks.

How can I fix this?

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.main .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
  
.main .row .col-6 {
    width: 200px;
}
    
.main .row .col-6 div {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    background-color: #888;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="main">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div>Rectangle 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div>Rectangle 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div>Rectangle 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div>Rectangle 4</div>
        </div>
        <!--
        <div class="col-6">
            <div>Rectangle 4</div>
        </div>
        -->
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kcdmkk12/11/)

Comment: Are you open to using javascript? Asking because I'm not sure how this can be done with pure CSS

Comment: @sol I know, it can be done by javascript, but I don't want to use it.

Comment: do you mean this ? https://jsfiddle.net/kcdmkk12/5/

Comment: @M.R.Safari It is a sandbox. I mean if you uncomment fifth box in html, scroll element try to accommodate all boxes, but I want to show only 4 boxes on initial screen, and other boxes when scroll down.

Comment: @Evgeniy im sorry. wrong link . try this https://jsfiddle.net/kcdmkk12/7/

Comment: @M.R.Safari No, as you can see, there are five box in scroll element in your decision. I'am sorry too, update jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kcdmkk12/11/

Comment: I don't think this is possible in CSS without declaring a `height` / `max-height` on the container. Otherwise container will just increase to accommodate new columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `height` setting to  `.main .row` and `.main .row  .col-6` as shown in my snippet to avoid the reduction of the heights:

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.main .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;  /* added */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.main .row .col-6 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50%;  /* added */
}

.main .row .col-6 div {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff;
  background-color: #888;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="main">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div>Rectangle 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div>Rectangle 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div>Rectangle 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div>Rectangle 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div>Rectangle 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the same thing in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1sdqn0hg/1/